# Can't Pass Messages with Servo/Ipc_channel for Rust

Tags: rust, ipc, pseudocode, channel

I'm stuck on implementing [Servo/ipc_channel](https://github.com/servo/ipc-channel). I'm looking for a trivial example to do the following. I've read through all the documentation and I just can't find an example that makes sense to me either from the [docs](https://doc.servo.org/ipc_channel/index.html) or from the [test.rs](https://github.com/servo/ipc-channel/blob/master/src/test.rs).

Here's what I want to do in pseudocode -

I have a cargo crate that acts as a `main process` that creates a `spawned process`.

The `main process` would look like this -

```
let servername = CREATESERVER();
let (sender, receiver) = GETSERVER(servername);
let message = <Some message>
sender(<Send message>)
SPAWNSERVER(servername)
loop{
print(receiver)
}
```

The `spawned process` should look like this -

```
let (sender, receiver) = GETSERVER(servernamefrommainprocess)
let messagespawn = <Some message in spawn process>
sender(messagespawn)
loop{
print(receiver)
}
```

The issue is that IpcSender can connect to a server by name, but IpcReceiver *can't*, so I don't know how to receive messages from an IpcOneShotServer. The examples are wrapping IpcSenders within other channels in a way I don't understand.

Here's what I have for a trivial working [repo](https://github.com/patientplatypus6/servoproblemexample), which is close to what I want and should give you an idea of what I'm looking to do.

Comment: From the descriptions and examples: once you connect your sender to the server, you need to create a channel and send the sender to the server so the server can use it to send messages to your receiver.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working with the owner of the repo here: https://github.com/servo/ipc-channel/issues/306. I'm close, but I don't have the pattern down quite yet. Right now I'm having an issue with 'assertion failed: self.port == MACH_PORT_NULL'. There isn't a trivial example between a server and child process, so if this gets answered it should help a bunch of people.